# Scraping dl,dt,dd HTML data

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to pull publicly available house descriptions from an online search using Rvest & Selectorgadget and attempting to follow several of the online tutorials for scraping the web however I am getting nothing returned. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

```
Site <- "https://paol.snb.ca/paol.html?lang=en&pan=00100004"
snb <- read_html(Site)
snb %>% html_nodes("dd") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: That site has lots of JavaScript things going on (including a use modal), so the data is probably being loaded dynamically and not in the source that rvest grabs. If so and provided scraping is allowed, you'd need to use something more heavy-duty like splashr or RSelenium to run the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks alistair, I was reaching this conclusion myself, I've tried to download Rselenium but it wont install due to an error:  *** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'. I'll try splashr in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `RSelenium`. Instead, you can play clever and use the hidden API instead, which is much faster:

Get API URL in network tab using developer tools in Chrome:

[image]

Instead of using the original URL, use the hidden API instead: `https://paol.snb.ca/pas-shim/api/paol/dossier/00100004`

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
myurl <- "https://paol.snb.ca/pas-shim/api/paol/dossier/00100004"
#you can use any user agent here
ua <- user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36")
my_cookie <- "copy_your_cookie_from_broswer_otherwise_request_will_fail_given_error_no_cookie_available"
my_session <- html_session(myurl,ua,
                         add_headers(Cookie=my_cookie))

result_list <- httr::content(my_session$response,as="parsed") # response is a json string and you will get a list using httr::content
```

Sample result:

```
> result_list$summary
$`taxAuth`
[1] "137 - HAUT-MADAWASKA"

$currAsst
[1] 7500

$curLevy
[1] 156.64

$pan
[1] "00100004"

$asstYear
[1] 2018

$imageKey
[1] ""

$description
[1] "Recreational Lot"

$location
[1] "1036 RTE 215"
```

Comment: Thanks Yifu, I made selenium work but might try to improve the process using your approach

Comment: That's great. Selenium is easy to use and good for testing. But if you want to make a fast and reliable scraper, then it's better to use basic requests.